# How to activate CORS in keystonejs 5 for the default application?

Tags: keystonejs

How to activate CORS in keystonejs 5 for the default application?
I tried it

```
module.= {
    configureExpress: app => {
        app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:8080' }));
    },
    keystone,
    apps: [new GraphQLApp(), new StaticApp({ path: staticRoute, src: staticPath }), adminApp].
};
```

and

```
module.= {
    keystone,
    apps: [new GraphQLApp(), new StaticApp({ path: staticRoute, src: staticPath }), adminApp],
    cors: { origin: 'http://localhost:8080' },
    distDir
};
```

But Access-Control-Allow-Origin does not appear in the request header.